# How to find if two objects will collide?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, parametric

The U.S.S. Carlton comes onto the screen on the lower edge at $200$ mm.  The U.S.S. Schmidt enters the screen on the left edge at $200$ mm.  At a time $1$ minute later, each ship has moved to a new location.  The U.S.S. Carlton has gone $5$ mm North and $2$ mm East of its previous position.  The U.S.S. Schmidt has moved $20$ mm East and $5$ mm North of its previous position.  Will these two ships collide if they maintain their speeds and directions?  If not, how close do they actually come to each other?

First, I solved for parametric equations for both ships:

> $\begin{align}\text{USS Carlton - }&x(t)= 200+2t \\
> \text{USS Carlton - }&y(t) = 5t\\
> \text{Schmidt - }&x(t) = 20t\\
> \text{Schmidt - }&y(t) = 200+5t\end{align}$

Next I turned these into regular rectangular equations these being:

> $\begin{align}\text{Carlton - }&y= 2.5x-500 \\
> \text{Schmidt - }&y=\frac14x +200\end{align}$

These numbers are correct as I have checked them with the answer booklet. 
Now, I must find if these two ships collide. I do not know how to do this, but I do know how to find the Point of Intersection. To find POI I set the two equations equal to eachother.
The POI I got was $(311.11,277.78)$
This is all I know how to do. 
Please, push me in the right direction.
Thank you

Comment: The ships do not collide if they are both at the point of intersection, but only if they are both at the point of intersection **at the same time**.  So you must not remove time from your equations.  Find whether or not there is a value of $t$ such that $x$ is the same for both ships and $y$ is the same for both ships.

Comment: Now that you have the point of intersection, find the time that each ship is there.  Plug one of your coordinates, say $x$ into the parametric equation and solve for $t$

Comment: This is not particularly clear, but I read "the bottom edge of the screen at 200mm" to be (0,-200) and "the left edge at 200" to be (-200,0).  The parametric equations are  Carlton: $(+2t, -200+5t)$ and Schmidt: $(-200+20t,5t).$  Regardless, both ships have the same amount of northerly travel, so as long as they have some north-south separation at $t= 0$ that remains constant over time.